# Ubuntu 15.04 unsolvable graphic tearing

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 15.04, xorg, tearing

My Nvidia Geforce GTX 850m issues are:

- Tearing on everything( window moving, video in Smplayer, video online in Firefox and Chromium, Scrolling in both Firefox and Chromium)
- no vsync settings on the Nvidia Xserver settings Window.

My driver and system info is:

- System: Ubuntu 15.04
- Processor: Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40Ghz x 4
- Memory: 7.7 GiB
- Hard Drives: 1 TB
- Graphics Card:

  - Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller.
  - Nvidia GeForce GTX 850m.
  - Driver Version: 346.59 from nvidia-346-update

Its in Dual Boot with Windows 10.

What I've tried:

- xorg.conf configurations (triple buffer, usleep, powermizer maximum performance)
- X server settings (OpenGL: maximum performance, all antialiasing options all powermizer options)
- `ccsm` (Sync to Vblank, undirected, 120hz refresh rate)
- I have basically tried everything I found with "nvidia" "ubuntu" and "tearing".

I had Linux Mint and had the same tearing issues, among other severe graphics issues (Random freezing, etc.). I have no issues till now with my nvidia card with Windows 10.

Anybody got a solution?

Comment: It got worse... now I have black screen issues but it seems like it is just black screen because i hear the log in screen and when i blind-log in the cpu led lights up like its loging in. nomodeset allows me to see my log in screen but it crashes after puting in my password and restarts at the log in screen again.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar a problem with a K2000M on my laptop and using Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2.

Expecially using a second monitor, video tearing appeared on my primary display.

The solution was to use `ForceFullCompositionPipeline` together with `TripleBuffer`

First do `sudo nvidia-xconfig` if the X11 configuration file xorg.conf is absent, then

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add the line `Option "TripleBuffer" "On"` under the `Section "Screen"`:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "On"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "LVDS-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+840, DP-4: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

In order to be able to use ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On, one could modify the line `Option         "metamodes"` in xorg.conf, but the problem was that when using a secondary monitor, the monitors.xml file (for the display manager) in ~/.config was overriding any modification issued by X11 reading xorg.conf at login ([see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/362704)).

The solution for me was to run a script at login (using [System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications](http://www.howtogeek.com/189995/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.04/)) with the following command:

```
nvidia-settings --assign="CurrentMetaMode=LVDS-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+840 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }, DP-4: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On, rotation=left }"
```

where LVDS-0 is my primary display and DP-4 my secondary display (use `xrandr -q` for the display names)

The last lines of /var/log/Xorg.0.log now shows:

```
...
[   136.640] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "LVDS-0:1920x1080_60+0+840{ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On},DP-4:1920x1080_60+1920+0{ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On,rotation=left}"
...
```

and the video tearing disappeared...

Hope this helps on Ubuntu

Comment: In your `nvidia-settings` command, how can you explicitly set one of the screens as the primary monitor? I've tried inserting `--primary` and `primary=yes` in different places and with different capitalization to no avail.